# How can I tell if a DLL is ComVisible?

Tags: .net, dll, comvisible

I have a DLL that may or may not have its ComVisible attribute set to true.  I'm not sure how it was built, or with what attributes?  All I know is that it's a .Net DLL.  Simply put, how can I tell if it is Com Visible?

Sorry if this is a duplicate.  All of my searches about this return results that show how to *make* a DLL ComVisible.  I know how to do that.

Comment: Just run Tlbexp.exe.  It will complain when it doesn't find any types that are [ComVisible].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check the [ComVisibleAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute.aspx) of the assembly using reflection:

```
private static bool IsComVisible(string assemblyPath)
{
  var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);

  var attributes = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ComVisibleAttribute), false);

  if (attributes.Length > 0)
  {
    return ((ComVisibleAttribute)attributes[0]).Value;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); //Assembly.LoadFile, Assembly.Load

bool comVisible = asm.GetCustomAttributes()
                     .OfType<ComVisibleAttribute>()
                     .First()
                     .Value;
```

Comment: Got an error: `No overload for method 'GetCustomAttributes' takes 0 arguments`